# A lot of unnecessary requests

Tags: reactjs

I have Posts component:

```
class ProfilePosts extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }
    getData = async (url) => {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization' : `${window.localStorage.getItem('token')}`
            }

        });
        return await res.json();
    } 
    getPosts = async () => {
        if (window.location.pathname === '/profile/undefined%7D')
        {
            window.location.pathname = `/profile/${window.localStorage.getItem('id')}`
        }
        await this.getData(`https://api.com/posts/${window.location.pathname.slice(9)}`)
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({posts: data}
               ); 
        })
       
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('id') !=  ''){
        this.getPosts();
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('id') != ''){
            this.getPosts();
        }
    
    }
    renderItems(posts){
        return Object.values(posts).map(post => {
                return (
                    <ProfilePost likes={post.likes} comments={post.comments} userId={window.localStorage.getItem('id')} token={window.localStorage.getItem('token')} Postid={post.id} key={post.id} sender={post.sender} content={post.content} time={post.sent_time}/>
                )
        });
    }
    
    render() {

        const {posts} = this.state;
        const items = this.renderItems(posts);
        return(
        <div className="profile-posts">
            {items}
        </div>
    );}
}

export default ProfilePosts;
```

I don't understand what is the reasons for re-rendering this component so many times (I don't know the actual number but it's huge). Therefore, a lot of requests to the database, and so on. How can I fix this?
I tried using another state but that didn't work for me. If you press the button, the state changed and then I checked if the state changed then I call `this.getPosts()` and then set the state to false again. It caused `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.`

Answer (score 2):

Your `componentDidUpdate` runs every time the component updates, after render, so it's calling `this.getPosts();`, which in turn calls `setState`, which results in another re-render and update, and so on.

Remove the `componentDidUpdate` entirely and let the `componentDidMount` method (which implements the same logic) alone take care of things.

Comment: That did not work for me. It renders only at the start. I want to rerender the component when, for instance, a person left a post. In the case of  ```componentDidUpdate```it will not load and the user will need to refresh the page.

Comment: Does anything else in the application indicate when a post update needs to happen, or is the data purely on the server? If it's on the server only, there's no way to update the local state unless you either implement continuous polling (say, every 30 seconds) or use a WebSocket to allow the server to send data to the client.

Comment: Actually yes, I tried to implement that thing. I wrote about it under the code.

Comment: What do you mean, you implemented that thing? Do you have something that creates a websocket and forces a re-render when it sends a new message? Or is your `componentDidUpdate` an attempt at implementing polling logic?